# multiple if and a single else condition

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am having multiple if in my controller action
**As mentioned below**
`if()
{
}
if()
{
}
if()
{
}
if()
{
}` 
Now i want a single else (execute when all if condition fails..i.e false)

Comment: And i dont want to use multiple else if(is it possoible without else if)

Comment: Why don't you want to use `else if`? I am asking because that's exactly what you should use to achieve the desired effect. Maybe you can show us your real code and explain what exactly you are trying to achieve as there might be a better way.

Comment: Smells like Strategy pattern. Can you give you code? OR you may look at this: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx

Comment: @DarinDimitrov if you are using else if it will only get executed only if the if condition fails, but if you are using multiple if's they will fire regardless of the previous if

Comment: @VamsiKrishna, yes, that's correct. That's why I asked for more details about what exactly the OP is trying to do here. Because without more details and actual context this question is pretty meaningless.

Comment: @Filburt although switch is a good thought, i don't think it will be very useful in the scenario, switch will be similar to else-if here, please read my above comment

Comment: guys there is nothing like useful or useless.. i am asking this question only for my own convention(not code).

Comment: And you got your answers. What you are trying to achieve is illogical - and there is no magic in code (except in Zen Cracking of course). Definition: _"a conditional is a compound statement formed by combining two sentences (or facts) using the words "if ... then."   A conditional can also be called an implication."_ There is no magical combination between one conditional and another, so you have to create one, like it or not. And the way to do it is either by combining the conditionals by another conditional (else if, or another nested if).

Comment: @Darin `else if` is really ugly  - I worked on teams where the usage of `else if` was banned on pain of death ;-)

Comment: @Filburt, we are not really constructive here without a specific scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a boolean variable as a flag and set it to true when a if condition is true
then you can use that flag to check whether at-least one if block was a sucess

Answer (score 6):

```
bool failed = true;
if() { failed=false; } if() { failed=false; } if() { failed=false; } if(failed) {}
```

Comment: @dhiraj "I don't want to learn how to drive a car - I just want to go from A to B."